# HttpRequest body encapsulation in an async URL fetch call in GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, url, soap, asynchronous, fetch

I wonder if it is possible to enclose a request body for an HTTPRequest when making HTTP calls using async url fetch in GAE?

I need to enclose SOAP envelopes in my HTTP POST messages and I would like to do some processing while the SOAP response is returned.

From the API, it doesn't seem to be possible. I wonder if anybody knows of any trick or any alternative workaround?

Any suggestion is very much appreciated.

thanks

Comment: Python or Java? Also, it's impossible - at the HTTP level - to attach a body to a GET request.

Comment: Java. so what do you think the solution is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the low level Java urlfetch API, async requests are handled the same way as synchronous ones: call `fetch[Async]` with an [HTTPRequest object](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/urlfetch/HTTPRequest.html). Before calling it, populate the body by calling `setPayload` on it. Note that it's impossible to attach a body to a GET request - only POST, PUT, etc requests can have bodies.

Comment: great thanks Nick. You are right, it should be an HTTP POST message for the SOAP envelope to get attached to. I edited my post to reflect on using POST instead. thanks again.